# Xcode sort CLLocations by distance to user location

Tags: xcode, distance, cllocation

After I spendet lots of time googling I decided to ask here. I hope someone can help me.

In my project I have some CLLocations with names to each of them.
Now I want a list, maybe a tableview or something similar that the user can see which of the locations are the nearest. How can I do that? Is there an easy way to do that?

Greekings Valle

Answer (score 0):

Determining the distance is just algebra:

```
#include <math.h>
double distance = sqrt(pow(myLat - theirLat, 2.0) + pow(myLong - theirLong, 2.0));
```

Sort all your distances and display how you want.

Creating a UITableView out of that is a much larger discussion and you should probably read a book or take the free Stanford course on iTunesU or something.

Comment: the distance wasn't the problem, the sorting was